# Is it possible to pass django model objects in the datalist of an ajax function?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to create a dynamic dependent dropdown list. My attempt is not working as the options are not being loaded, on running the server.

Scenario is a model with fields: *scenario_id* and *scenario_name*.

The url name *Get_Scenario* links to the view function *get_scenario* given below.

My .html file

```
<form action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-5" id="orgdiv">
    <select class="form-control" id="txtOrganization" >
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Organization</option>
        {% for organization in Organization %}
            <option value="{{ organization.org_id }}">{{ organization.org_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-5" id="scenariodiv">
   <select id="txtScenario" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Scenario</option>
    </select>
```

My ajax function

```
$('#txtOrganization').on("input", function () {
       if (scenarios) {
           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {% url 'Get_Scenario' %},
            data: {scenarios: scenarios},
            success: function (data) {
                var udata = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    udata = udata + "<option value='"+ scenarios[i].scenario_id + "'>" + scenarios.scenario_name + "</option>"

                }
                $("#txtScenario").append(udata);
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

views.py

```
def get_scenario(request):
    org_id = request.GET.get('org_id')
    organization = Organization.objects.get(pk=org_id)
    scenarios = organization.scenario_set.all()
    return scenarios
```

I feel the problem lies in passing the django model object *scenarios* to the ajax function datalist, and perhaps it's not able to access the fields in the Scenario model. Do I need to mention the object scenarios in the data list? Or it'll work without it

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: are you want to pass `scenarios` django objects by ajax?

Comment: No I wanted to get it into ajax. Realized that and made an edit

Comment: where's your `scenarios` data in script from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's impossible.

When your `scenarios` context passed to django template, it will rendered to string. django automatically complied object to template. That's what django `Context` and `Template` do.

It means, all rendered context will be `string` in template, including your javascript. That's way people use `serialize`.

For more information about `serialize`, check docs below

- [serilalizing django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/)

If you want to send request using `ajax`, all data you want to send is `string`, not django object.

So, if you want to pass scenarios data in ajax, you can just pass your scenarios' id.

Then in your view (`{% url 'Get_Scenario' %}`), you can get your object lists from that id list and pass it to data. like below

In your views, just pass `scenarios_ids` like `organization.scenario_set.values_list('id', flat=True)` and serialize it for using inside javascript.

`scenarios_ids_data = json.dumps(list(scenarios_ids))`

And template, use `scenarios_ids_data`

```
$('#txtOrganization').on("input", function () {
       var scenarios_ids = '{{ scenarios_ids_data }}';
       if (scenarios) {
           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {% url 'Get_Scenario' %},
            data: {scenarios: scenarios_ids},
            success: function (data) {
                var udata = "";
                // also you will received serialized data and use it here
                }
                $("#txtScenario").append(udata);
            }
        });
        }
    });



                $("#txtScenario").append(udata);
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm not clear with one thing, where does serialization have to be done?

Comment: One more clarification which I needed, how will I access the objects having the id passed to the template?

Comment: You have to do serialization in view. You can use `django.core.serializers` or just can use `json.dumps` for make your object data to string.

Comment: Also you will pass your id data from view by accessing from it. i.e. by `scenario_ids = Scenario.objects.value_list('id', flat=True')`, you can get your id list. and pass it using json, `scenario_ids_json = json.dumps(scenario_ids)`. just pass it to template and use `var scenario_ids_json = "{{ scenario_ids_json }}";`